# How can i redirect to another page or i can link my qml files. qt creator

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator, arcgis

I am making a mobile application on ArcGIS AppStudio.

I want to navigate to another page. For example, I am on my login page, so after I hit the login button i want to redirect to home page.

How can I do it? I am a beginner at this so do not have much idea how to solve it.

I have tried this:

```
Button {
    text: "MyButton"
    onClicked: loader.source = "MyFile.qml" //loader = id of Loader
}
```

After this when I hit the login button the page which I want to redirect to loads there along with the login page.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [StackView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-stackview.html#replace-method)

In `main.qml`

```
StackView {
    id: mainStack
    anchors.fill: parent

    Component.onCompleted: {
        // if not logged in
        mainStack.push('Login.qml');
        // else push another
    }
}
```

In `Login.qml`

```
Page {

    property StackView mainStack: StackView.view


    footer: Button {
        text: "Login"
        onClicked: mainStack.replace("Home.qml")
    }

}
```

Property just for easier access to mainStack

Comment: actually i don't have main.qml file. i have login page as my main page and then the home page. so can i apply stackview on login page??

Comment: Ypu can put login `Page` inside `StackView`, but i prefer split `Page`s into separate files